# jquery expression to remove not working

Tags: jquery

When I disable some fields on my form I am trying to remove the jquery validation errors. I am almost there but there is something wrong in my expression. Here is my html when the div is in error...

```
<div class="ym-fbox ym-error">
   <label for="selectedDate">
      Selected Date
      <sup class="ym-required">*</sup>
   </label>
   <input id="selectedDate" class="{required:true,repManDate:true,dpDate:true} datepicker hasDatepicker disabled" type="text" data-target="selectedDate" value="" name="selectedDate" disabled="disabled">
   <p class="ym-message" for="selectedDate" generated="true">Please enter a valid date</p>
</div>
```

I would like to remove the ym-error class and also remove the whole p tag that holds the error message. Here is my js. The removal of the ym-error class works but the remove on p.ym-message does not. Can someome tell me what is wrong?

...

```
   var field = $("#selectedDate");
   removeErrors(field);
```

and then...

```
function removeErrors(element) {
    var closetDiv = $(element).closest('div');
    $(closetDiv).removeClass('ym-error'); 
    $(closetDiv).remove('p.ym-message'); 
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a selector is passed to remove method, remove method filters the selected elements and will remove the matched element so there is no element inside collection of retrieved `closetDiv` which is a paragraph with class `ym-message`.

So you need to do:

```
$(closetDiv).find('p').remove('.ym-message');
```

or:

```
$(closetDiv).find('p.ym-message').remove();
```

instead of:

```
$(closetDiv).remove('p.ym-message');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E8R2s/)**